# Confused on Fourier Transform. What is amplitude spectrum and phase?

Tags: fourier

I am learning fourier transform by myself and I am confused on the description below.

[image]

I can't understand how can I get the second formula by using the Euler formula on the first equation. Why is there no summation symbol in the second equation?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3191593/532586

Comment: If you don't need to satisfy a college professor, I recommend learning DFT from a book that is more practical, like this one:  The Scientist & Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing by Steven W. Smith

Comment: No need to look too deeply into this; the \$\small k'th\$ sinusoidal frequency component has an amplitude and a phase angle, hence it can be expressed by the 2nd equation.

Comment: Fourier Transform is just correlation, with pre-defined basis functions ---- thus pure trigonometry suffices to understand the behaviors.